# Making Guitar Rig 5, Spotify and Guitar Pro 6 be routed to my headphones

Tags: electric-guitar, software, guitar-effects

I'm a electric guitar player and I like to Jam along to tunes. My current setup is my guitar, plugged into my ME-25, which is hooked up to my computer (Windows 7) with a USB cable, using ASIO4ALL v2 and finally the sound comes out to my headphones on the standart output jack of my PC. To get the most out of my sound, I use Guitar Rig 5 to apply distortions, delays and such, using my FX pedal as a interface only.
But when Guitar Rig is open, none of the other programs, such as Chrome (youtube),  Guitar Pro, and Spotify can get their sound routed to my headphones. I want to be able to hear every other sound while playing guitar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I use Guitar Rig with ASIO4All and have noticed it locks the sound to itself.  I can not play any other audio while GuitarRig or Amplitube (which both uses the ASIO driver).  You can open a sound file with Guitar Rig's player and play songs and backtracks that way.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to successfully play spotify (or any other "system sound" source) with Reaper while using Amplitube/Bias as a VST plugin. I imagine Guitar Pro/Rig has a similar way to get it's sound into a DAW. For bonus, you can combine different VST plugins and record as well with a DAW.

Also, I highly recommend using the official ASIO drivers, rather than generic ASIO4ALL drivers: http://roland.com/support/article/?q=downloads&p=ME-25

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the me-25 (I have a Stealth Pedal), but you ought to use the ASIO driver from Roland's website.

If you do this, you will have then two audio devices.

This should enable you to use the outputs on the ME-25 for guitar (select ME-25 as both in and out for guitar rig). The PC onboard sound device will no longer be locked when using Guitar Rig.

This *will* require two sets of speakers (or a hardware mixer to one set, **or a y-splitter**). I have a 150 watt AV receiver with stereo speakers and subwoofer connected to my Pedal for guitar and a set of PC speakers for "PC noises."